# Reading the content of a Javascript-rendered webpage into R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I am trying to read the content of the following webpage (as shown in the Inspect Element tool of my browser) into R:

[Etoro Discover People](https://www.etoro.com/discover/people/results?copyblock=false&hasavatar&maxmonthlyriskscoremax=5&dailyddmin=-10&gainmin=5&period=OneYearAgo&displayfullname&verified&isfund=false&gainmax=100&maxdailyriskscoremax=5&maxmonthlyriskscoremin=1&copiersmax=5000&copytradespctmax=0&copyinvestmentpctmax=0&tradesmin=20&winratiomax=85&weeklyddmin=-20&profitableweekspctmin=50&highleveragepctmax=10&lowleveragepctmin=50&longpospctmax=80&activeweeksmin=24&lastactivitymax=14&sort=-gain&page=1&pagesize=20&preset=preset_five)

Since the content is apparently Javascript-rendered, it is not possible to retrieve content by using common web scraping functions like `read_html` from `xml2` package. I have come across the following post that suggests using `rvest` and `V8` packages, but I could not get it to work for my problem:

https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/

I have also seen very similar questions on Stack Overflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262108/scraping-javascript-rendered-content-using-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691757/r-web-scraping-with-rvest-and-v8)), but the answers to those questions (the hidden api solution and the Request URL in the Network tab) did not work for me.

For starters, I am interested in reading the public ID of people in the list (the `div.user-nickname` node). My guess is that either I am specifying the node incorrectly or the website does not allow web scraping at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see that class when looking at the supplied link. Can you give an example id from the page to be retrieved?

Comment: @QHarr Thank you very much for your response. For example, the ID of the second person on the list is "brandnew300".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is coming from an API call returning json. You can make the same GET request and then extract the usernames. Swop `x$UserName` with `x$CustomerId` for ids.

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.etoro.com/sapi/rankings/rankings/?activeweeksmin=24&blocked=false&bonusonly=false&copiersmax=5000&copyblock=false&copyinvestmentpctmax=0&copytradespctmax=0&dailyddmin=-10&displayfullname=true&gainmax=100&gainmin=5&hasavatar=true&highleveragepctmax=10&isfund=false&istestaccount=false&lastactivitymax=14&longpospctmax=80&lowleveragepctmin=50&maxdailyriskscoremax=5&maxmonthlyriskscoremax=5&maxmonthlyriskscoremin=1&optin=true&page=1&pagesize=20&period=OneYearAgo&profitableweekspctmin=50&sort=-gain&tradesmin=20&verified=true&weeklyddmin=-20&winratiomax=85')

users <- lapply(data$Items, function(x) {x$UserName})
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

When I copy-paste the json you have provided into my browser, I am able to see its content, but I cannot read it in R. When I run the second line of your code, I get the following error message:
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open URL ''[...]": HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

How can I resolve this issue?

My second question is how did you get this new URL (the json one) from the original URL? I am really sorry, I am so inexperienced in web scraping.

Comment: Press F12 whilst on the webpage to open dev tools, go to the network tab, press F5 watch the web traffic appear as page updates. Look through the web traffic (filtered on xhr) for the request beginning with`https://www.etoro.com/sapi/rankings/rankings/?activeweeksmin`

Comment: Sorry, I have got another question. It seems that each json that I retrieve for a given list of people contains only 20 items (and not all the people on the list). For example, the json you provided contains 20 people while the original list (in my original URL) contains 30 people. I tried your solution on another list (with 2207) people, and got 76 jsons each containing 20 people (I scrolled down to load the entire list of people and then extracted the json URL's from dev tools). Is there a way I can retrieve the names of ALL people on the list (either in 1 json or in multiple ones)?

Comment: check the params within the url. Is there a limit and/or paging?

Comment: Yes, there is a "pagesize=20" and a "page=n" (with different n's) within each URL. Here is one of the 76 URL's that are associated with the list with 2207 people: http://www.etoro.com/sapi/rankings/rankings/?blocked=false&bonusonly=false&client_request_id=00ce1691-cb4d-490a-a746-585a1f1834e7&copyblock=false&country=74&hasavatar=true&instrumentid=-4&isfund=false&istestaccount=false&lastactivitymax=30&optin=true&page=40&pagesize=20&period=LastTwoYears&profitablemonthspctmin=50&sort=-copiers&tradesmin=5&verified=true

Comment: you need to investigate altering those. If the actual website has a next page button/more results button click that whilst watching the network tab to see if additional requests are made.